# How to disable and then re-enable a Windows 10 user account in latest Version 1803, OS build 17134.228

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

UPDATE: I've since noticed the same issue, but for WIN7, in .../questions/96883/

ORGINAL: In earlier versions of WIN 10 I was able to temporarily disable a user account. There are numerous hints on the web how to do this.

But since a minor WIN 10 update today (and possibly since the last time I did this successfully, over a year ago) I can only delete an account:

Settings/accounts/Family & other people/

and at the Local account (under +Add someone else to this PC) it offers only the options to:

- Change account type
  or
- Remove

The option to temporarily disable seems to be unavailable now.

I have tried searching here and also tried using the earlier(?) route via cmpmgmt.msc, but that doesn't seem to work now.

Advice appreciated. - iSeeker

Answer (score 1):

It should still be possible to use Computer Management to do this.

Given that you haven't actually specified what doesn't work in this route, I assume you couldn't find the disable function, so I'm presenting it once more.

You right-click the user, then choose properties.

From there, check Account is disabled.

Hit apply and ok to set this. Repeat the steps, but this time uncheck it, and the account is enabled again.

Given that you don't actually mention WHY you want to do this, I can't tell you if it will solve whatever problem it is that you try to solve, but this will indeed temporarily disable that account in Windows 10, any version.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your advice - I'd already tried the steps you recommend. The strange thing is that when I get into Computer Management, e.g. via Windows administrative Tools, or via other routes, the list of folders under System tools doesn't have an entry for "Users and Groups"  between Shared Folders and Performance. It's just not there. Putting Users and Groups into Cortana merely takes me to a web search. If I go via /Settings/Accounts/Family etc., then as described in the Question. Thanks again.

Comment: Further: I've found a Microsoft Live Chat helpline, which has made me some suggestions.  If they work, I'll post the results here later.

Comment: Do you happen to use the Home version of Windows 10? It may be missing the users and groups functionality in Home editions of windows.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. It's on a LeNovo laptop that originally came with 8.1 and I accepted all subsequent updates to Win10; I'd found nothing online to suggest that a Home version might be different. I'll check next time I boot it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is Win 10 Home. 
The MS Live Chat suggested: 
To disable a local account without deleting it                                                   
   CMD > net user "User Name" /active:no
To re-enable it
   CMD> net user "User Name" /active:yes                                                                   
But a related superuser question for WIN 7 Home (now visible to me, though it didn't show up on earlier searches)   … /questions/96883/ 
reckons the same approach didn’t work. 
I’ll try it when I’ve got time to rebuild the account if it screws up.
Thanks Roger and LPChip.

Answer (score 0):

My client has the same version and OS build as yours. We could disable/enable account with following pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Roger, I've only belatedly realised Picture2 was a separate hint, and will try it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Roger, I think LPChip's point about Windows 10 Home not displaying "Users and Groups" means I can't find Guest properties either, even after searching in a number of ways. Last hope is the Microsoft Live Chat helpline suggestion.

Comment: sorry for that. hope you can find solution.

Comment: Thanks, Roger. The annoying thing is that I did successfully and easily disable and then re-enable the spare login about a couple of years ago (I just wanted to be sure while I was on holiday that other family members would take another machine and not hog mine). Then it was either an 8.1 version, or one of the subsequent Win 10 updates overrode the capability.